# Go template.ExecuteTemplate include html

Tags: go, go-templates

I have followed this tutorial: http://golang.org/doc/articles/wiki/final.go and have slightly modified it for my needs/wants. The problem is I would like to support HTML in the templates. I realize this is a security risk but it's not a concern at the moment.

The result of a page render:

```
<h1>this<strong>is</strong>a test</h1>
```

Let me explain a little bit of the code:

```
type Page struct {
    Title string
    Body  []byte
}
```

The data I would like to have HTML is stored in `Page.Body`. This is type `[]byte` which means I can't (or can I?) run `html/template.HTML(Page.Body)` as that function expects a string.

I have this which pre-renders the templates:

```
var (
    templates = template.Must(template.ParseFiles("tmpl/edit.html", "tmpl/view.html"))
)
```

And the actual `ExecuteTemplate` looks like this:

```
err := templates.ExecuteTemplate(w, tmpl+".html", p)
```

Where w is `w http.ResponseWriter`, tmpl is `tmpl string`, and p is `p *Page`

Finally my `'view.html'` (template) looks like the following:

```
<h1>{{.Title}}</h1>
<p>[<a href="/edit/{{.Title}}">edit</a>]</p>
<div>{{printf "%s" .Body}}</div>
```

**Things I have tried:**

- `{{printf "%s" .Body | html}}` doesn't do anything
- I have included `github.com/russross/blackfriday` (Markdown processor) and have run `p.Body = blackfriday.MarkdownCommon(p.Body)` which correctly converts Markdown to HTML, but the HTML is still output as entities.
- **EDIT:** I have attempted the following bit of code (I don't know why the format is messed up) and it still outputs the exact same.

  `var s template.HTML`
  `s = template.HTML(p.Body)`
  `p.Body = []byte(s)`

Any guidance is greatly appreciated. If I'm being confusing please ask and I can modify my question.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Convert your `[]byte` or `string` to type `template.HTML` (documented [here](http://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#HTML))

```
p.Body = template.HTML(s) // where s is a string or []byte
```

Then, in your template, just:

```
{{.Body}}
```

It will be printed without escaping.

**EDIT**

In order to be able to include HTML in you page's body you need to change the `Page` type declaration:

```
type Page struct {
    Title string
    Body  template.HTML
}
```

then assign to it.

Comment: That doesn't work. I receive the following message: `cannot use "html/template".HTML(p.Body) (type "html/template".HTML) as type []byte in assignment`

Comment: don't just copy-paste and say it doesn't work. you obviously need to change the type of your Body field to be able to assign something of type template.HTML to it.

Comment: Please see the Edit I made last night to my question right after I posted the comment. I did make a change to the type of Body and I'm still seeing the exact same results.

Comment: I added a function called 'noescape' that converts a string to `template.HTML`, then `printf` to it in a pipeline. Works magic.

Comment: I spent a couple of days getting very angry at my template for working when I passed strings, but not when I passed html strings...

Thanks!

Answer (score 22):

Take a look at the [template.HTML](http://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#HTML) type. It can be used to encapsulate a known safe fragment of HTML (like the output from Markdown). The "html/template" package will not escape this this type.

```
type Page struct {
    Title string
    Body template.HTML
}

page := &Page{
    Title: "Example",
    Body:  template.HTML(blackfriday.MarkdownCommon([]byte("foo bar")),
}
```

I usually write my own `func Markdown(text string) html.Template` method that calls blackfriday with the appropriate config and does some type conversions. Another alternative might be also to register a "html" func in the template parser, that allows you to output any value without any escaping by doing something like `{{html .MySafeStr}}`. The code might look like:

```
var tmpl = template.Must(template.New("").Funcs(template.FuncMap{
    "html": func(value interface{}) template.HTML {
        return template.HTML(fmt.Sprint(value))
    },
}).ParseFiles("file1.html", "file2.html"))
```

Answer (score 21):

I created a custom function for the template as follows:

```
func noescape(str string) template.HTML {
    return template.HTML(str)
}

var fn = template.FuncMap{
    "noescape": noescape,
}
```

Then on your template:

```
{{ noescape $x.Body }}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's an approach that doesn't require any changes to your existing structs, and a very minimal, additive change to your templates:

Change these lines:

```
var (
    templates = template.Must(template.ParseFiles("tmpl/edit.html", "tmpl/view.html"))
)
```

to this (include a funcmap with a function that will output un-escaped HTML):

```
var templates = template.Must(template.New("main").Funcs(template.FuncMap{
    "safeHTML": func(b []byte) template.HTML {
        return template.HTML(b)
    },
}).ParseFiles("tmpl/edit.html", "tmpl/view.html"))
```

And then just change your template HTML from this:

```
<div>{{printf "%s" .Body}}</div>
```

to this (use your new function):

```
<div>{{ .Body | safeHTML }}</div>
```

Much easier!

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Beego and React.js and fought for hours trying to get the JSX parser to run. Turns out html/template strips out comments especially the js doc block /** @jsx React.DOM */.

Got around it by creating a special method to Type the comment as JS and calling it from within the template.

```
// Create a method in your controller (I'm using Beego)
func jsxdoc()(out template.JS) {
    return template.JS(`/** @jsx React.DOM */`)
}

// Add method to your function map available to views
beego.AddFuncMap("jsxdoc", jsxdoc)

// In template
<script type="text/jsx">
    {{ jsxdoc }}
    var CommentBox = React.createClass({
      render: function() {
        return (
          <div class="commentBox">
            Hello, world! I am a CommentBox.
          </div>
        );
      }
    });
    React.renderComponent(
      <CommentBox />,
      document.getElementById('content')
    );
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For clarification and a much simpler way of passing HTML to template, see

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/8L4eDkr5Q84

Just create your HTML string via go and pass it into your template, e.g.:

```
Sout := ""
.
.

    Sout += fmt.Sprintf(`<tr><td>%s<td align=center>%.2f<td>%s<td>%s<td>%s<td>%s<td align=center>%d<td align=center>%d
                    <td align=center>%d`, AccountID, amount, remissiondetails, created, begins, ends,
                    freePDFs, freeinformants, freeSDQs)

.
.
    render(w, "templates/Waivers.html", map[string]interface{}{ "Body":template.HTML(Sout), })
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case (where I am populating a view `struct` with a list of `Activity`), I had to change the property `Message string` to `Message template.HTML`. Then, when setting the property value I can call `activity.Message = template.HTML("The <b>HTML</b>")`.

Answer (score -1):

Why not convert the `[]byte` to a string?  You can do it like this:

```
str := string(page.Body)
```

Comment: I tried that, the issue is `template.ExecuteTemplate` needs a pointer to Page which requires it to be a `[]byte` I tried doing exactly what you mentioned and received the following error: `cannot use string(p.Body) (type string) as type []byte in assignment` . Likewise changing my struct to use a string instead of a []byte caused other issues when saving the content to file.