# Show parsed html string from database to template using Golang

Tags: html, templates, go

Given my model

```
type Criteria struct {
    ...
    CriteriaID      string        `db:"criteria_id"`
    CriteriaName    string        `db:"criteria_name"`
    ...
```

and controller

```
func CriteriaReadGET(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    .....
    // Display the view
    v := view.New(r)
    v.Name = "criteria/read"
    v.Vars["criteria"] = result
    v.Render(w)
}
```

One of the column in the result (query result from my model) contain html tags, which is generated from ckeditor or similar plugin.

When I pass the output to my template,

```
{{.CriteriaName}}
```

it shows the html tags like

```
<ul>
<li>One</li>
<li>Two</li>
</ul>
```

How to show the content to looks like

- One
- Two

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50441026/show-parsed-html-string-from-database-to-template-using-golang

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just got the answer from another post I got after I post this question.
Here's the post: [Go template.ExecuteTemplate include html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18175630/go-template-executetemplate-include-html)

All I need to change is from

```
type Criteria struct {
    ...
    CriteriaID      string        `db:"criteria_id"`
    CriteriaName    string        `db:"criteria_name"`
    ...
```

to

```
type Criteria struct {
    ...
    CriteriaID      string        `db:"criteria_id"`
    CriteriaName    template.HTML `db:"criteria_name"`
    ...
```

Hope this help someone having the same question.