# Is there any solution to render html like this in gin?

Tags: go, go-gin

I want to render templete like this, but I can't find relative code from website.

page.tmpl

```golang
<html>
  <body>
  {{.a}}
  </body>
<html>
```

router code piece

```golang
aEle = `<a>I 'm tagA</a>`
r.GET("/page", func(c *gin.Context) {
  c.HTML(200, "page.tmpl",  gin.H{"a":aEle,}})
})
```

result like this

```html
page
<html>
  <body>
    <a>I'‘m tagA</a>
  </body>
<html>
```

Comment: [`html/template`](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/) package. E.g. [`Template.Execute()`](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#Template.Execute) method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Go template.ExecuteTemplate include html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18175630/go-template-executetemplate-include-html)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can just do:

```
var aEle template.HTML = `<a>I 'm tagA</a>`
```