# How to render user posts with links but no other html?

Tags: javascript, html, go, html-templates

I'm building a website similar to twitter. A user can make a post and mention another user using the `@username` notation.

At first I was going to parse each post server side and add html tags around the `@mentions`, then render the post as a `template.HTML` (I'm using `Go` server side), but then I realized that users would be able to add any html they want, and I don't want that. Is there a way to render the posts as `html` while ignoring any `html` that the user tries to upload? Any code/markup that they upload should be shown in plain text.

Or will it be better to add the markup around the `@mentions` client side using `javascript`?

Comment: what is `template.HTML`?

Comment: It's a `type` in `go`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18175630/go-template-executetemplate-include-html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great worry! This type of HTML injection from user input is a real problem, fortunately, there’s an easy fix, you can escape HTML characters so the browser understands that there’s a literal “<“ character in the text, not the start of a HTML element.

In Go, there’s  the [`html.EscapeString`](https://pkg.go.dev/html#EscapeString), which you pass the user input and then can safely use inside HTML. So you would sanitize the input and after that parse it and link the `@mentions`.